# Integrate Symfony with cas server

Tags: symfony-2.1, cas

I want to integrate cas server with symfony, i found [besimplessoauthbundle](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle)

I configured it lik this :

```
be_simple_sso_auth:
admin_sso:
    protocol:
        id: cas
        version: 4
    server:
        id: cas
        login_url: Url-to-cas-server/login
        logout_url: Url-to-cas-server/logout
        validation_url: Url-to-cas-server/serviceValidate
```

And in security.yml like this :

```
    firewalls:
    my_firewall:
        pattern: ^/
        trusted_sso:
            manager: admin_sso
            login_action: BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle:TrustedSso:login
            logout_action: BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle:TrustedSso:logout
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /check_path
            create_users: true
            created_users_roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
        logout:
            path:          /logout
```

When connecting to cas server and redicted to my websitepage i get this error :

```
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

So i add this to parametrs.ylml :

```
be_simple.sso_auth.client.option.curlopt_ssl_verifypeer.value: 0
be_simple.sso_auth.client.option.curlopt_ssl_verifyhost.value: 0
be_simple.sso_auth.client.option.curlopt_certifinfo: 0
```

But now iget this eeror :

```
SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name
```

Did i miss anythings , i use cas server verision4 and symfony 2.6 , How do i get ride af the error ?
Im looking also for other implementation of cas server and symfony2

Comment: Is your CAS server presenting a self signed certificate when you visit it over HTTPS?

Comment: No. Can i create one on the server ?? its a local server and not a public one.

Comment: I disabled curlopt_ssl_verifypeer so how can i deal with the second error !
If my Cas Server does not present a self signed certificate and i disabled the certificate check so where do the problem come !